# How to localize database table

Tags: sql, localization

what's the best way to localize a database table, holding for example a Country?

## 1 Flat Table

```
CountryID|Code|NameEN|NameIT
----------------------------
1        |IT  |Italy |Italia

SELECT CountryID, Code, NameEN AS Name
FROM Countries
```

## 2 Joined Tables

```
CountryID|Code
--------------
1        |IT

CountryID|LocalizationCode|Name
---------------------------------
1        |EN              |Italy
---------------------------------
2        |IT              |Italia

SELECT CountryID, Code, Name
FROM Countries INNER JOIN CountriesLoc ON Countries.CountryID = CountriesLocs.CountryID
WHERE LocalizationCode = 'EN'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it depends. How many languages are you going to have? Or will it be just English and the country's language?

Comment: There could be any number of languages. Imagine an e-commerce backend, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend going with the second option, although you appear to have some data-typos.

Country:

```
Id  Code
===============
1   IT
```

Localized_Country:

```
CountryId  LanguageCode  LocalizedName
=========================================
1          IT            Italia
1          EN            Italy
```

Which you then query like so:

```
SELECT a.Id, b.LocalizedName
FROM Country as a
JOIN Localized_Country as b
ON b.CountryId = a.Id
AND b.LanguageCode = :InputLanguageCode
WHERE a.Code = :InputInternationalCountryCode
```

Wrap that (or something similar) up in a view, and you're golden.

Some recommendations:
You may want to push `Language` (or some other type of `Locale` concept) into it's own table.  The key can either be an auto-increment value, or the international characters, doesn't much matter which.
Make sure to put a unique constraint on `(CountryId, LanguageCode)`, just in case.  And never forget your foreign keys.

Comment: Why are you adding "WHERE a.Code = :InputInternationalCountryCode"?

Comment: Because I need something that says exactly which country I'm talking about, independent of the language/localization.  For countries, this would be the ISO standard codes (2/3 letters).  If I wanted the list of all countries, then I'd leave it off.  You didn't give the end application, but for a website, you'd be passing the ISO code for country based parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I will go with second one, it's more flexible, just remember to create index on CountryId column in the second table.

I've just noticed your query:

```
SELECT CountryID, Code, Name
FROM Countries INNER JOIN CountriesLoc ON Countries.CountryID = CountriesLocs.CountryID
WHERE LocalizationCode = 'EN'
```

why are you adding

> where LocalizationCode = 'EN'

Do you assume that for country Italy can be more than one language?

EDITED

```
    SELECT CountryID, Code, Name
FROM Countries INNER JOIN CountriesLoc ON Countries.CountryID = CountriesLocs.CountryID
WHERE Code = 'EN'
```

Comment: Because if I'm using the frontend in Italian I want to output "Italia", otherwise in English I want to output "Italy".

Comment: ok, i get it. but then i think more efficient will be to filter on Code column - see my edited answer for sql

Comment: But "Code" will never be 'EN' because the international code for Italy is 'IT'. Sorry, my example was not very useful...

Comment: Then I think you should add EN into first table and when deciding what language to use do something like that: code = is_language_selected ? "lan_selected_by_user" : 'EN'. I think it will be much more efficient to filter by Code than LocalizationCode.